# Randomized (as in QuickCheck) versus deterministic (as in SmallCheck) property checking

Tags: haskell, testing

I know of two approaches to property checking:

- Randomized approach (as in QuickCheck) makes you define a generator of random values for your types, then verifies your invariants for each of a large number of randomly generated cases. For example, in case of a vector space ℤⁿ (defined, say, as `[Word]`), it would generate vectors of any length and direction.
- Deterministic approach (as in SmallCheck) works the same, except that it generates valus from simple and small to more complex and extensive deterministically, covering *(as I understand)* a small part of domain tightly. For example, in the same case as above, it would generate zero vector, then all vectors of length <= 1, then all vectors of length <= 2, and so on, eventually covering all *interesting* values (such as unit vectors), for which there may conceivably be unforeseen corner cases that break an invariant.

Did I get it correct? What are the benefits and downsides of either approach? What are the preferred use cases for either? Maybe, for best results, both approaches should be combined, say, covering some moderately sized "base" with a deterministic checker and then a random sample with a randomized one?

I'm looking for some solid, motivated best practice to use daily and advance from now on.

---

P.S. This question is not intended to provoke discussion. I am asking specifically what benefits either approach to property checking has matter-of-factly, not which is nicer, easier to use or better by any other measure that can be considered a matter of taste. An answer would provide either a critique of the problem posed, a mindful, mathematical observation of the nature of either method of property checking, or a case / experience report that justifies one of the approaches as preferable for a certain class of situations. In the end, I intend this question to generate a set of criteria that help determine which approach to testing will catch more programming mistakes. Put this way, I don't see how this question could be considered subjective in any way other than good, as outlined in [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). There is a [companion reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7tq1hl/what_to_favour_for_property_checking_quickcheck/?ref=share&ref_source=link) that offers a channel for more liberal communication.

Comment: I'm not aware of SmallCheck, but assuming that by ℤ you mean the set of all integers, I don't see how, if it were to generate *all* vectors of length 1, it would ever be able to progress to generating vectors of length 2, and so on.

Comment: @MarkSeemann it wouldn't, but it would e.g. generate all the vectors of length 2 which contain only entries abs-smaller than 3.

Comment: I wonder why someone down-voted this question. Is it because it looks like a solicitation of opinions?

Comment: This question seems like it's looking for a discussion, rather than concrete answers. Not a good fit for SO IMHO, though it'd be an interesting topic for a blog post.

Comment: @Cubic I read through the help center section on good and bad questions again and it still appears to me that my question matches the points for the good better. In particular, [there is a subsection concerning good subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that I would like to direct your attention to. I will edit my question further in a minute; please tell me what you think after the update.

Comment: The way you test your software depends entirely on the particulars of the software. As it stands this question is much too broad; no text short of 500 pages could hope to discuss the 'best practices' for testing. Besides this, I think the topic of deterministic vs. randomized testing is fairly well explored; you should identify some specific questions regarding their distinction that would guide you to a solution to your problem.

Comment: @user2407038 You say it's fairly well explored; can you share some links?